# Publicly available archive NEAR RPC API?

Tags: nearprotocol

Looking for a node that has pre-indexxed the NEAR blockchain so I can query for idempotent historical data. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at https://docs.near.org/docs/api/rpc#setup

> endpoint URL varies by network:
>
> - mainnet https://rpc.mainnet.near.org
> - testnet https://rpc.testnet.near.org betanet
> - https://rpc.betanet.near.org (may be unstable) localnet
> - http://localhost:3030
>
> Querying historical data (older than 5 epochs or ~2.5 days), you may
> get responses that the data is not available anymore. In that case,
> archival RPC nodes will come to your rescue:
>
> - mainnet https://archival-rpc.mainnet.near.org
> - testnet https://archival-rpc.testnet.near.org